# What is the total energy of newtonian polytrope stars of index $n > 5$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, ideal-gas, equilibrium, stars

In *classical newtonian theory*, we could find a general expression for the gravitational potential energy of a polytrope sphere (of pressure $p(\rho) = \kappa \rho^{\gamma}$, where $\gamma = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ is the *adiabatic index* of the fluid).  At static equilibrium, assuming $\gamma > 1$:
$$\tag{1}
U_{tot} = - \frac{3}{5 - n} \frac{G M^2}{R}.
$$
Since the pressure can also be written as $p = (\gamma - 1) \rho_{int}$ (where $\rho_{int}$ is the *internal* energy density), we could apply the virial theorem and find the total kinetic energy:
$$\tag{2}
U_{tot} + 3 \int_{\mathcal{V}} p \, d^3 x = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad K_{tot} = - \frac{n}{3} U_{tot}.
$$
Then
$$\tag{3}
E_{tot} = K_{tot} + U_{tot} = - \frac{3 - n}{5 - n} \frac{G M^2}{R}.
$$
Hence, $E_{tot} < 0$ (gravitationally *closed* system) for $n < 3$ ($\gamma > \frac{4}{3}$), $E_{tot} = 0$ for $n = 3$ (i.e ultra-relativistic fluid of index $\gamma = \frac{4}{3}$), and $E_{tot} > 0$ (gravitationally *open* system) for $3 < n \le 5$.  This is all fine.  But I'm wondering what happens for fluid balls of index $n > 5$ ($1 < \gamma < \frac{6}{5}$).  Expression (1) cannot be valid in their case since the potential energy should stay negative.  So they should have an infinite extension: $R \rightarrow \infty$, and possibly also an infinite mass.  But what about (3), which is *negative* if I allow $n > 5$?  The integrals that lead to these expressions are probably divergent when $n > 5$ (so we couldn't apply the virial theorem), but I don't see that clearly.

So the question is what should we say about (3) for $n > 5$?  What happens for polytropic fluid spheres of index $n > 5$?  What is their total energy?  $E_{tot} \rightarrow - \infty$?

**EDIT:** In the special case of $n = 5$ ($\gamma = \frac{6}{5}$), we could solve analytically the hydrostatic equilibrium equation and find the total mass and radius.  The radius $R$ is infinite, while the total mass $M$ stays finite.  The potential energy integral also converges, so $(5 - n) R$ in (3) stays finite under the limit $n \rightarrow 5$ and $R \rightarrow \infty$ (this is pretty amazing, by the way!).  The total mechanical energy is finite and *positive* for $n = 5$:
$$\tag{4}
E_{\text{tot}, \, n = 5} = \frac{3 \pi p_0}{8 \rho_0} \, M,
$$
where $p_0$ is the central pressure, $\rho_0$ is the central mass density and $M$ is the total mass:
$$\tag{5}
M = \int_0^{\infty} \rho(r) \, 4 \pi r^2 dr = \frac{18}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \, \rho_0 \Bigl( \frac{p_0}{G \rho_0^2} \Bigr)^{3/2}.
$$
I still don't know what happens for $n > 5$ ($\gamma < \frac{6}{5}$), except that both $M$ and $R$ are infinite.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot answer your question. But I remember that $n=\infty$ is sometimes used to model globular clusters.

Answer (score 1):

As polytropic index approaches infinity, pressure becomes linear, i.e.
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \kappa \rho ^{1+1/n} = \kappa \rho \tag 1$$

Also you can check the limit,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{3 - n}{5 - n} = -1 \tag 2$$

Or if you prefer , you can expand it in series about $n=\infty$, so that

$$ -\frac{3 - n}{5 - n} = -1 - \frac 2n - \frac{10}{n^2} - \frac{50}{n^3} - \frac {250}{n^4} + \ldots \tag 3$$

So it's clearly seen that terms other than first,- vanish very quickly, and you are left just with $-1$.

Hence total energy limit at infinite polytropic index,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} {E_{tot}} = -\frac {GM^2}{R} \tag 4$$

approaches constant negative value. Albeit I'm not qualified enough to explain what it means.

However wiki says about [polytrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrope):

> A polytrope with index n = ∞ corresponds to what is called an isothermal sphere, that is an isothermal self-gravitating sphere of gas, whose structure is identical to the structure of a collisionless system of stars like a globular cluster. This is because for an ideal gas, the temperature is proportional to $ρ^{1/n}$, so infinite n corresponds to a constant temperature.

> In general as the polytropic index increases, the density distribution is more heavily weighted toward the center (r = 0) of the body.

Last statement in my head issued some analogies to black holes, because we have singularity there with infinite density, but my intuition may or may not have any real consequences of $n=\infty$.

Comment: This cannot be quite right, since for $n\geq5$, the polytrope never has a finite radius $R$ at which the density goes to zero.  The whole expression becomes undefined.

Comment: @Buzz, for $n > 5$ (excluding $n = 5$, see my edit), both $M$ and $R$ are infinite, and it's possible that $M^2/R$ remains finite under some proper limit.

Comment: @Buzz Well, my given limits are mathematically correct (you can check them in any symbolic algebra package). But I'm not sure about $-\frac {GM^2}{R}$ part,- is it finite, infinite, or undefined as you say in the polytropic limit. That depends how $M(n),R(n)$ functions depends on $n$. If they are independent on it, well that's a constant value then. Btw, you should skip $n=5$ case in the limit (2) analysis, because it produces discontinuity. We evaluate things for $n>5$.

Comment: The numerical integration of the hydrostatic equilibrium equation clearly shows that the potential energy goes to infinity for all $n > 5$: $U_{tot} = - \infty$.  So the expression $G M^2 / R$ do diverges, even if $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $M \rightarrow \infty$.  Also, we get $K_{tot} \rightarrow \infty$ (from the numerical integration).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The kinetic energy $K_{tot}$ is the volume integral of the internal energy $\rho_{int}$ and is positive if it converges.  The potential energy $U_{tot}$ is another volume integral, and is negative, if it converges.  The virial theorem for a polytrope gives
$$\tag{A}
U_{tot} + 3 (\gamma - 1) K_{tot} = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad K_{tot} = - \frac{n}{3} U_{tot}.
$$
If both integrals converge, then
$$\tag{B}
E_{tot} = K_{tot} + U_{tot} = - \frac{n - 3}{3} U_{tot} = \frac{n - 3}{3} |\, U_{tot}|.
$$
This mechanical energy is *positive* for $n > 3$, and so also for $n \ge 5$, if the integrals that define $K_{tot}$ *and* $U_{tot}$ converge.  It is the case for $n = 5$, but apparently not for any $n > 5$ since the potential energy (1) in the question gets the wrong sign.  According to the numerical integration of the hydrostatic equilibrium equation that I've done, the potential energy integral diverges so that $U_{tot} = -\, \infty$.  The virial theorem is then inapplicable and (B) isn't valid for $n > 5$.

Since the integrals diverge (it's obvious from the numerical integration), and also $M \rightarrow \infty$, $R \rightarrow \infty$ for all $n > 5$, the mechanical energy is infinite: $E_{tot} \rightarrow + \infty$.